# Why my Android Application on my Galaxy s5 crashes?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mobile

[2016-03-27 16:50:23 - Contacts_App] ------------------------------

[2016-03-27 16:50:23 - Contacts_App] Android Launch!

[2016-03-27 16:50:23 - Contacts_App] adb is running normally.

[2016-03-27 16:50:23 - Contacts_App] Performing com.TeeJayA.contacts_app.MainActivity activity launch

[2016-03-27 16:50:26 - Contacts_App] Uploading Contacts_App.apk onto device '45f7c0f0'

[2016-03-27 16:50:26 - Contacts_App] Installing Contacts_App.apk...

[2016-03-27 16:50:33 - Contacts_App] Success!

[2016-03-27 16:50:34 - Contacts_App] Starting activity com.TeeJayA.contacts_app.MainActivity on device 45f7c0f0

[2016-03-27 16:50:35 - Contacts_App] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.TeeJayA.contacts_app/.MainActivity }

**Everything seemed to Install but it Crashes on Opening.
I had the minsdkVersion at 17 then 14 and now 4, Still Crashes.
My Galaxy s5 is Running v5.0.
I haven't tried emulators yet but intend to.
Want to use s5 because its quicker.
What am I doing wrong ??**

Comment: Post error logs from logcat here

Comment: Does it crash on EVERY device, including emulators, or just this specific device? The above posted code is pretty standard commands adb does when starting any app from AS and really doesn't tell anything why its crashing - Define `I run my Application Successfully it Seems but Crashes immediately after Opening.` - how is that successful?